# Chai.js: expect object.to.contain.all.keys not asserting values

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js, chai

I am using [Chai.js](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) to assert that an object has at least some of keys with their values.
I am wondering that it's not asserting for values, just asserting for keys.

`expect({ foo: 5, bar: 3 }).to.contain.all.keys({ foo: 6 });`

The previous passes! why?

Comment: That's the purpose  of contain all keys. Use to.deep.equal instead, if you want to compare the values also.

Comment: @Hosar, I mentioned "at least", to.deep.equal asserts that two objects are identical in number of keys which I don't need . I've updated my question now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is **include**:

```
expect({ foo: 5, bar: 3 }).to.include({ foo: 5 }); //Passes
expect({ foo: 5, bar: 3 }).to.include({ foo: 6 }); //Doesn't pass
```